# Find the lowest recursive in SQL table

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I need to get the lowest parent in the hierarchy data. I have a problem in getting the lowest parent id. Please see the query and the expected results below. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
 CREATE TABLE #Modules ([ModuleId] INT, [ModuleName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [ParentId] INT NULL)

INSERT INTO #Modules
SELECT 1, 'Master', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'UsersGroup2', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'UsersGroup3', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'UsersGroup4', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'UsersGroup5', 4
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'UsersGroup6', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'UsersGroup7', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'UsersGroup8', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'UsersGroup9', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'UsersGroup10', 9
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'UsersGroup11', 10
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 'UsersGroup12', 11
UNION ALL SELECT 14, 'UsersGroup14', 12
UNION ALL SELECT 15, 'UsersGroup15', 9


;WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS [Level], [ModuleId], 
             [ModuleName] AS [GrandParent], [ModuleName], [ParentId]
             FROM #Modules
             WHERE [ParentId] IS NULL
             UNION ALL SELECT cycle.[Level] + 1, base.[ModuleId], 
             cycle.[GrandParent], base.[ModuleName], base.[ParentId]
             FROM #Modules base
             INNER JOIN CTE cycle ON cycle.[ModuleId] = base.[ParentId])
SELECT CTE.ModuleId, CTE.ParentId AS GrandParentId, COALESCE(NULLIF([GrandParent],[ModuleName])+'-->'+[ModuleName],[ModuleName]) AS [ModuleName]
FROM CTE

DROP TABLE #Modules
```

Results:

```
ModuleId    GrandParentId     ModuleName
1            NULL             Master
8            NULL             UsersGroup8
9            NULL             UsersGroup9
10            9               UsersGroup9-->UsersGroup10
15            9               UsersGroup9-->UsersGroup15
11            9               UsersGroup9-->UsersGroup11
12            9               UsersGroup9-->UsersGroup12
14            9               UsersGroup9-->UsersGroup14
2             1               Master-->UsersGroup2
3             1               Master-->UsersGroup3
4             1               Master-->UsersGroup4
5             1               Master-->UsersGroup5
6             1               Master-->UsersGroup6
7             1               Master-->UsersGroup7
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does the query work?

Comment: @kbball, the query is working however the grandparent that I am getting is wrong. You can run the query to see the results. I already put the expected results too.

Comment: Gotcha - is there some upper limit on how many steps back you would need to go? Or do you want something flexible enough to handle any number of "recursions"

Comment: @kkball- there's no limit. It should be flexible. Thank you.

Comment: Add the tag for the database you are in, you will get more specialized attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the ParentID as the GrandParent in your recursive CTE. This is changing as you join back to the CTE to get all of the levels.

If you define the GrandParentID field as well in the top level and refer to it in the second level of the CTE, you'll get the answer:

```
with data1 as(
SELECT 1 [ModuleId], 'Master' [ModuleName], NULL [ParentId]
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'UsersGroup2', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'UsersGroup3', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'UsersGroup4', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'UsersGroup5', 4
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'UsersGroup6', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'UsersGroup7', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'UsersGroup8', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'UsersGroup9', NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'UsersGroup10', 9
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'UsersGroup11', 10
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 'UsersGroup12', 11
UNION ALL SELECT 14, 'UsersGroup14', 12
UNION ALL SELECT 15, 'UsersGroup15', 9
)

, CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS [Level], [ModuleId], [ModuleId] GrandParentID ,
             [ModuleName] AS [GrandParent], [ModuleName], [ParentId]
             FROM data1
             WHERE [ParentId] IS NULL
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT cycle.[Level] + 1, 
             base.[ModuleId], 
             cycle.GrandParentID,
             cycle.[GrandParent], 
             base.[ModuleName], 
             base.[ParentId]
             FROM data1 base
             INNER JOIN CTE cycle ON cycle.[ModuleId] = base.[ParentId])
SELECT CTE.ModuleId, GrandParentId,COALESCE(NULLIF([GrandParent],[ModuleName])+'-->'+[ModuleName],[ModuleName]) AS [ModuleName]
FROM CTE
```

or in your format:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS [Level], [ModuleId], [ModuleId] GrandParentID, 
         [ModuleName] AS [GrandParent], [ModuleName], [ParentId]
         FROM #Modules
         WHERE [ParentId] IS NULL
         UNION ALL SELECT cycle.[Level] + 1, base.[ModuleId], 
         cycle.[GrandParent], base.[ModuleName], base.[ParentId]
         FROM #Modules base
         INNER JOIN CTE cycle ON cycle.[ModuleId] = base.[ParentId])
SELECT CTE.ModuleId, CTE.GrandParentId, COALESCE(NULLIF([GrandParent],[ModuleName])+'-->'+[ModuleName],[ModuleName]) AS [ModuleName]
FROM CTE
```

Comment: thank you. I tested your query and it's working! Can you please explain your query?

Comment: This is really getting you the Level 1 ID and Name, which you are referring to as GrandParent. GrandParent could also mean the Parent's Parent. Updated the answer for clarity on what is happening